# Sharing an excel file with multiple data connections with other excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-sharing, power-query

I have built an Excel dashboard.

The data that was used to build it is in my system and as the data files were very large in size, I have used data connections to take pivots and make charts.

but when I am sharing the files (Dashboard and Data) the data connections are not working.

After downloading the shared file when I go to edit and source in the power query editor from a different system it's still taking the directory of my system.

How can I prevent this, and share a file with multiple data connections without using a server or database? is it even possible?

If it is possible, Any help or direction to resources would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no native way to do this in PQ, so combine two methods:

- Create a parameter table which you can use in your Source step(s), as per Ken Puls article here: https://excelguru.ca/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/
- Use the CELL function to generate the folder path the current workbook is stored in, as a value in the parameter table.

Comment: Hi Adam It helped me a lot.  I got the parameter table-building part and Kind of got the intention of the article. But at the end, it says we can use this table (File path for me) reference to get data. That part I am struggling with.